# path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install Gelatin for python 3 with pip and I am getting this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\abejd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u3685bna\SimpleParse\setup.py", line 108, in <module>
    **extraArguments
  File "c:\python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "c:\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 557, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "c:\python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_egg_info.py", line 34, in run
    self.run_command('egg_info')
  File "c:\python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 279, in run
    self.find_sources()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 306, in find_sources
    mm.run()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 533, in run
    self.add_defaults()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 569, in add_defaults
    self.read_manifest()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 201, in read_manifest
    self.filelist.append(line)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 475, in append
    path = convert_path(item)
  File "c:\python36-32\lib\distutils\util.py", line 125, in convert_path
    raise ValueError("path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname)
ValueError: path '/home/mcfletch/OpenGL-dev/simpleparse/simpleparse/stt/TextTools/mxTextTools/mxTextTools.c' cannot be absolute
```

I have tried 2 solutions but to no avail have I solved the problem. If there is any other information that I can provide to try and fix this please let me know. 
Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: installing without pip, changing pythons path, trying it in 2.6

Comment: So, what's your question? It's pretty obvious that that *is* an absolute path. If the error says that they aren't allowed, well...

Comment: ...and https://github.com/mcfletch/simpleparse/blob/master/setup.py is quite intentionally converting paths to be absolute. Huh. I'd suggest talking with its maintainership, which is to say, filing a ticket at https://github.com/mcfletch/simpleparse

Answer (score 2):

The problems seem to be related to the `C:\Users\maparama\Documents\SimpleParse-2.2.0\SimpleParse-2.2.0\SimpleParse.egg-info\SOURCES.txt`

Steps

1. Download the package from
   https://pypi.org/project/SimpleParse/#files
2. Remove the `SimpleParse.egg-info/` directory
3. perform python `setup.py` install.

```
C:\Users\maparama\Documents\SimpleParse-2.2.0\SimpleParse-2.2.0>pip list
Package        Version
-------------- -------
gelatin        2.2.10 <---
lark-parser    0.6.4
lxml           4.2.5
pip            10.0.1
PyYAML         3.13
robotframework 3.0.4
setuptools     40.4.3
simpleparse    2.2.0
```

Comment: This works for other packages too, apparently. I was struggling to install sktime and this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with pg-chameleon, caused by this rows in setup.py:

```
conf_dir = "/%s/pg_chameleon/configuration" % python_lib
conn_dir = "/%s/pg_chameleon/connection" % python_lib
sql_dir = "/%s/pg_chameleon/sql" % python_lib
sql_up_dir = "/%s/pg_chameleon/%s" % (python_lib, sql_up_path)
```

Error looked like:

```
ValueError: path '/f:\work\pycharmprojects\virtualenvironments\mysql2psql\Lib\site-packages/pg_chameleon/configuration' cannot be absolute
```

I solved this issue by downloading pg_chameleon-2.0.10.tar.gz and editing setup.py it (I removed '/' before '%s')
Then i did:

```
pip install "path-to-my-package"
```

and got

```
Successfully installed pg-chameleon-2.0.10
```